# Why is the later version of Cg compiler producing shader using more instructions?

Tags: pixel-shader, cg

I have a shader that looks like this:

```
void main( in   float2              pos         : TEXCOORD0,
           in   uniform sampler2D   data        : TEXUNIT0,
           in   uniform sampler2D   palette     : TEXUNIT1,
           in   uniform float       c,
           in   uniform float       th0,
           in   uniform float       th1,
           in   uniform float       th2,
           in   uniform float4      BackGroundColor,
           out  float4              color       : COLOR
         )
{
    const float4 dataValue = tex2D( data, pos );
    const float vValue = dataValue.x;
    const float tValue = dataValue.y;

    color = BackGroundColor;
    if ( tValue <= th2 )
    {
        if ( tValue < th1 )
        {
            const float vRealValue = abs( vValue - 0.5 );
            if ( vRealValue > th0 )
            {
                // determine value and color
                const float power = ( c > 0.0 ) ? vValue : ( 1.0 - vValue );
                color = tex2D( palette, float2( power, 0.0 ) );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            color = float4( 0.0, tValue, 0.0, 1.0 );
        }
    }
}
```

and I am compiling it like this:

```
cgc -profile arbfp1 -strict -O3 -q sh.cg -o sh.asm
```

Now, different versions of Cg compiler creating different output.

- cgc version 2.2.0006 is compiling the shader into an assembler code using 18 instructions:

  ```
  !!ARBfp1.0
  PARAM c[6] = { program.local[0..4],{ 0, 1, 0.5 } };
  TEMP R0;
  TEMP R1;
  TEMP R2;
  TEX R0.xy, fragment.texcoord[0], texture[0], 2D;
  ADD R0.z, -R0.x, c[5].y;
  CMP R0.z, -c[0].x, R0.x, R0;
  MOV R0.w, c[5].x;
  TEX R1, R0.zwzw, texture[1], 2D;
  SLT R0.z, R0.y, c[2].x;
  ADD R0.x, R0, -c[5].z;
  ABS R0.w, R0.x;
  SGE R0.x, c[3], R0.y;
  MUL R2.x, R0, R0.z;
  SLT R0.w, c[1].x, R0;
  ABS R2.y, R0.z;
  MUL R0.z, R2.x, R0.w;
  CMP R0.w, -R2.y, c[5].x, c[5].y;
  CMP R1, -R0.z, R1, c[4];
  MUL R2.x, R0, R0.w;
  MOV R0.xzw, c[5].xyxy;
  CMP result.color, -R2.x, R0, R1;
  END
  # 18 instructions, 3 R-regs
  ```
- cgc version 3.0.0016 is compiling the shader into an assembler code using 23 instructions:

  ```
  !!ARBfp1.0
  PARAM c[6] = { program.local[0..4], { 0, 1, 0.5 } };
  TEMP R0;
  TEMP R1;
  TEMP R2;
  TEX R0.xy, fragment.texcoord[0], texture[0], 2D;
  ADD R1.y, R0.x, -c[5].z;
  MOV R1.z, c[0].x;
  ABS R1.y, R1;
  SLT R1.z, c[5].x, R1;
  SLT R1.x, R0.y, c[2];
  SGE R0.z, c[3].x, R0.y;
  MUL R0.w, R0.z, R1.x;
  SLT R1.y, c[1].x, R1;
  MUL R0.w, R0, R1.y;
  ABS R1.z, R1;
  CMP R1.y, -R1.z, c[5].x, c[5];
  MUL R1.y, R0.w, R1;
  ADD R1.z, -R0.x, c[5].y;
  CMP R1.z, -R1.y, R1, R0.x;
  ABS R0.x, R1;
  CMP R0.x, -R0, c[5], c[5].y;
  MOV R1.w, c[5].x;
  TEX R1, R1.zwzw, texture[1], 2D;
  CMP R1, -R0.w, R1, c[4];
  MUL R2.x, R0.z, R0;
  MOV R0.xzw, c[5].xyxy;
  CMP result.color, -R2.x, R0, R1;
  END
  # 23 instructions, 3 R-regs
  ```

The strange thing is that the optimization level for the cg 3.0 doesn't seems to influence anything.

Can someone explain what is going on? Why is the optimization not working and why is the shader longer when I compiled with cg 3.0?

Take a note that I removed comments from the compiled shaders.

Comment: The actual assembler code might give some clues, those 18/23 instructions shouldn't be too heavy to post here.

Comment: @Christian Ok, I posted the code, but SO decided to make it look bad. Can someone edit please and fix the code?

Comment: What about telling nVidia about this, as the second version seems obviously worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be a real answer to the problem but maybe give some more insight. I inspected the generated assembly code a bit and converted it back to high-level code. I tried to compress it as much as possible and remove all copies and temporaries that follow implicitly from the high-level operations. I used `b` variables as temporary bools and `f`s as temporary floats. The first one (with the 2.2 version) is:

```
power = ( c > 0.0 ) ? vValue : ( 1.0 - vValue );
R1 = tex2D( palette, float2( power, 0.0 ) );

vRealValue = abs( vValue - 0.5 );

b1 = ( tValue < th1 );
b2 = ( tValue <= th2 );

b3 = b1;

b1 = b1 && b2 && ( vRealValue > th0 );
R1 = b1 ? R1 : BackGroundColor;

color = ( b2 && !b3 ) ? float4( 0.0, tValue, 0.0, 1.0 ) : R1;
```

and the second (with 3.0) is:

```
vRealValue = abs( vValue - 0.5 );

f0 = c;
b0 = ( 0 < f0 );

b1 = ( tValue < th1 );
b2 = ( tValue <= th2 );

b4 = b1 && b2 && ( vRealValue > th0 );

b0 = b0;
b3 = b1;

power = ( b4 && !b0 ) ? ( 1.0 - vValue ) : vValue;
R1 = tex2D( palette, float2( power, 0.0 ) );

R1 = b4 ? R1 : BackGroundColor;

color = ( b2 && !b3 ) ? float4( 0.0, tValue, 0.0, 1.0 ) : R1;
```

Most parts are essentially the same. The second program does some unneccessary operations. It copies the `c` variable into a temporary instead of using it directly. Moreover does it switch `vValue` and `1-vValue` in the power computation, so it needs to negate `b0` (resulting in one more `CMP`), whereas the first one does not use a temporary at all (it uses `CMP` directly instead of `SLT` and `CMP`). It also uses `b4` in this computation, which is completely unneccessary, because when `b4` is false, the result of the texture access is irrelevant, anyway. This results in one more `&&` (implemented with `MUL`). There is also the unneccessary copy from `b1` to `b3` (in the first program it is neccessary, but not in the second). And the extremely useless copy from `b0` into itself (which is disguised as an `ABS`, but as the value comes from an `SLT`, it can only be 0.0 or 1.0 and the `ABS` degenerates to a `MOV`).

So the second program is quite similar to the first one with just some additional, but IMHO completely useless instructions. The optimizer seems to have done a worse job compared to the previous(!) version. As the Cg compiler is an nVidia product (and not from some other not to be named graphics company) this behaviour is really strange.

Comment: Your analysis is detailed and correct. So, we agree that there must be a bug in the latest compiler's version. Do you know where to fill a bug report? I already asked on nvidia's forum for cg, but received no response

Comment: @VJo Don't know either. Actually filing bugs shouldn't be that common with nVidia compared to AMD, but it seems to be one. But don't hesitate to post any results you may get from nVidia.